# target ="_blank" not working in IOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I am developing mobile app(IOS/android) UI with phonegap/cordova 2.1.0. I want to open a link given in href attribute of anchor tag in a new window/page. I tried :

```
target="_blank"
```

But it is not working in IOS. Any workaround available?. Thanks

Comment: Where do you expect it to open? If you are in Phonegap, there aren't any new windows/tabs?

Comment: That should work, according to the [Safari HTML documentation][1].
Could you post your code?
  [1]: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/html/attribute/target

Comment: In phonegap, can i not open another window/tab?

Answer (score 3):

If you can use JQuery :

```
<a href="http://link.com" rel="external">link</a>
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[rel="external"]').click(function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Sources](https://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/14623/target_blank-vs-jquery/p1)

Comment: I haven't found a parameter for window.open that will get it working in iOS. It always opens in the webview for me. (Phonegap Build 3.1.0)

Comment: Until I add <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" /> to config.xml and then it works in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

don't touch your javascript file, just write on your MainViewController.m file this code, before @end tag. I work with cordova framework like you.

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
  {

  NSString *url = request.URL.absoluteString;

  NSString *pathExtension = [[url lastPathComponent] pathExtension];

  if([pathExtension isEqualToString:@"pdf"]){

  ```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];

  return NO;
  ```

  }
  else if([[request.URL host] isEqualToString:@"www.yoururl.com"]){

  ```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];

  return NO;
  ```

  }

  return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
  }

Here you can view two different instructions, all pdf files will be open in a new window, and after on request.URL you need to wirte your url. If you www.yoururl.com/folder1/folder2 you don't need to write all the urls, because maybe you will have many different url. You just need to write the www.yoururl.com from your site.

Hope it helps for you, this works for me.
=)